# How to prevent reloading of images in listview with custom adapter when refresh listview

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, universal-image-loader

I am using `displayImage()` method of UniversalImageLoader library in the adapter class, which sets images(from url) in the list items. i want if i reset adapter in my listview, images should not reload if the urls are same as previous urls.

Comment: You want your listview to not show images then?

Answer (score 0):

There is two solution already posted in the issue section of `Universal Image Loader`.

[**Solution #1:**](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/395#issuecomment-24389369)

You can use custom displayer:

```
new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300) {

  @Override
            public Bitmap display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
                if (loadedFrom != LoadedFrom.MEMORY_CACHE) {
                    return super.display(bitmap, imageView, loadedFrom);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    return bitmap;
                }
            }

        }
```

**[Solution #2:](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/395#issuecomment-25402398)**

```
 BitmapDisplayer displayer = new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(500) {

        @Override
        public Bitmap display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView,
                LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
            if (loadedFrom != LoadedFrom.MEMORY_CACHE) {
                return super.display(bitmap, imageView, loadedFrom);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                return bitmap;
            }
        }

    };
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.thumbnail_no_image)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.thumbnail_no_image)
            .displayer(displayer).build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024).build();
    sLoader.init(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problema and went with a solution as follows

Inside the getview method after declaring your imageview try the following line as first line

```
myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.adefaultimage);
```

this will first show a defaultimage in the imagview and will avoid duplication of images till imageloader loads the real one

Comment: The point of using Universal Image loader is, it caches the image and prevents out of memory exception problem.

Comment: @YuvaRaj this's just a defaultimage of verysmall resolution/size that can be fetched from drawable to avoid duplication of images in listvie/gridview etc.In such views usuall UIL displays already displayed images once again until new image gets loaded.This can be avoided easily by this way and I have implemented that

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this :

Use android Lru cache in your list adapter. First time its looking very complex but its have more benifits.

Using Lru cache your image store in cache and when it will display then check from cache if it will exist then it will not down load and it will use from stored cache memory. You can also give cache memory size for your application and clear it.

Below have some links:

Tutorials:

1. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html

Example :

1. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/caching-bitmaps-with-lrucache.html
2. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/apply-lrucache-on-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried above solutions but not find usefull, Finally i solved my problem by saving images from url to device(as bitmap) then get in list view from there.